# If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $a \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ then $f$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ then $f$ is continuous at $a.$

I know this is of course true. I am currently reading Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis,* and I need some help understanding why it is true from the given definitions.

> Definition: Suppose $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^m,$ and $x \in E.$ If there exists a linear transformation $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(x+h) - f(x) - Ah|}{|h|} = 0,$$ then we say that $f$ is differentiable at $x,$ and we write $f'(x) = A.$

On the next page, Rudin states that

> This relation can be rewritten in the form $$f(x+h) - f(x) = f'(x)h + r(h)$$ where the remainder $r(h)$ satisfies $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|r(h)|}{|h|} = 0.$$

I can follow all of this reasonably well, but why does this immediately imply that $f$ is continuous at any point at which $f$ is differentiable? Rudin says that it follows without giving any reasons. I would love to see a short proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\frac{|r(h)|}{|h|}\to 0$, then certainly $r(h)\to 0$ when $h\to 0$. Since $x$ is fixed $f'(x)h\to 0$ when $h\to 0$. Therefore, $f(x+h)-f(x)\to 0$ when $h\to 0$.